# Why are spelled-out numbers below twenty considered stopwords in Spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Spacy considers spelled-out numbers below twenty like "five" or "eleven" to be stop words, it also considers "twenty", "thirty, ... "sixty" to be stopwords too.
I'm questioning the reason behind this. Seems like numbers are important information we don't want to dispose of?

Answer (score 0):

Stop words depend a lot on your task, so you can think of the list provided by spacy as one suggestion, but you'll frequently want to customize it.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
assert nlp.vocab["eleven"].is_stop == True
# remove 'eleven' as a stop word
nlp.vocab["eleven"].is_stop = False
assert nlp.vocab["eleven"].is_stop == False
```